# How to remove duplicates in a subquery using distinct in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I want to remove duplicate rows returned from this sql:

```
Select
      *
    From (Select
      Security_Symbol,
      Security_Name,
      date1,
      time1,
      last1,
      Changefromopen,
      percentchangefromopen
    From
      xgdv
    Where
      Security_Symbol In ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
    Order By
      date1 desc,
      time1 asc) where rownum <= 3
```

Using a distinct in subquery doesn't remove duplicate records.

What's wrong with using distinct in subquery. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try using `DISTINCT` in the outer query?

Comment: yes I did. same result.

Comment: Do you expect all of the fields to be unique? Or are you considering a duplicate two rows with equivalent `Security_Symbol` and `Security_Name` as the same row?

Comment: yes, later one.
subquery should return unique Security_Symbol.

Comment: Try adding the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause between the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY` clauses. `GROUP BY Security_Symbol`.

Comment: already did that, then it returns error like this : 'ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression'

Comment: adding all the selected columns in subquery to the group by clause seems to have worked : like this -> 

"
Group By 
          Security_Symbol,
          Security_Name,
          date1,
          time1,
          last1,
          Changefromopen,
          percentchangefromopen
        Having count(*) > 1
"

Is it correct/proper way to remove duplicates?

Comment: can you post sample records or a screenshot of your duplicate records.

Comment: I am not allowed to do that. sorry.

Comment: @GauravSharma: If your data is sensible, anonymize. If you want help, cooperate! Provide a test case to work with.

Comment: won't the time stamp values destroy any hope of having only 1 copy per item? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple rows with the same `Security_Symbol`/`Security_Name`, but only want one row for each combination in the result, then you need to decide what data you want. You may want the range of the other columns, as in:

```
Select
  Security_Symbol,
  Security_Name,
  min(date1), max(date1),
  min(time1), max(time1)
  min(last1), max(last1),
  min(Changefromopen), max(Changefromopen),
  min(percentchangefromopen), max(percentchangefromopen)
From
  xgdv
Where
  Security_Symbol In ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
Group by
  Security_Symbol, Security_Name
Order By
  Security_Symbol, Security_Name
```

This may not be the solution you are looking for; if it's not, please specify what data of the other columns you are interested in. For example: any random row, the average,...

Answer (score 0):

try calling all columns from the base table in the subquery - it might be more obvious which rows are similar. you could also try adding a rank to the subquery to highlight the duplicate rows. this would be a starting point to work out what is causing the dupes.